# Cancelar Background 'none !important' no funciona

Tags: css

Tengo este código:

```
<header style="background-image:url(http://www.......com/wp-)">
```

Despues con un estilo css

```
header{background-image:none !important}
```

Con responsive necesito volver a mostrar el fondo que cancele con `!important`

Había intentado usar `:unset !important`, `inerhit !important` e `initial !important` ninguna de las anteriores logra cancelar el comando CSS - `none !important`.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Usa media query:
`<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />`

Si no:

```
<style>
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
    //  Aquí poner el important.                                                         
    header{background-image:none !important}
    }
</style>
```

El media query debes adecuar lo tamaño necesario